# How to calculate the indefinite integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So my question simply is: what is $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\,d x $?

Comment: You can call the antiderivate the Peter Dam function and define $PD(x) = \int_0^x dy \sin(y)/\sqrt{y}$. (this is not a joke, it is essentially what has been done but due to bad luck there is already a different name attached to it)

Comment: You mean like the Fresnel-integrals?

Comment: It is exactly the Fresnel-integral... (after substitution $x=t^2$)

Comment: Wow... I had to look at them for a while, but now I think've I got it, thanks! And also, then this means that there isn't a 'real' antiderivative of this function?

Comment: (I just learned about the Fresnel-integrals about an hour ago)

Comment: The Fresnel functions are certainly "real".  They are just not elementary functions.

Comment: Oh yes, that is what I meant, I just couldn't articulate it well (I am not a native speaker). I found it weird because the derivative of the Fresnal integrals are elementary, but they are not themselves.

Comment: It's only weird because of the way calculus courses work.  Unfortunately, nearly all examples of integration that you see in calculus courses have elementary antiderivatives.  This is not at all indicative of "most" elementary functions.  If you write down an elementary function (not in one of the "easy" classes that you know how to integrate), it's very likely not to have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Other examples of elementary functions with non-elementary antiderivatives include  $\ln(x)/x$, $\exp(x)/x$, $e^{-x^2}$, $\cos(\sin(x))$, etc.